# Scale/move vertices outwards but still keep the original shape geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, transforms

I'm trying to scale an object in the X and Y direction and still keep the same shape.
My main issue is that, when i scale my object in the desired directions, then the distance between my walls are also increasing.

I feel that i've tried a billion different methods but i just cant figure it out.

Here's pictures of what im trying to do:
Basically, i'm trying to keep the walls at a constant thickness, in this case 2mm

Here is the original model - Diameter is 50mm and wall thickness is 2mm:
[image: Original model before scaling]

Here is what i would like my model to look like after the scaling:
Diameter 60mm and wall thickness 2mm
[image: Model after scaling]

This is what happens - the walls are thicker than before:
Diameter 60mm and wall thickness 2.4mm.
[image: This is what happens - the walls are thicker than before]

Comment: If you do not use a _Solidify_ modifier to create the inner walls with the given distance, it is simply not possible by scaling - scaling is multiplying by a factor (with a factor > 1 scaling upwards and < 1 downwards), so everything you scale will be mutliplied by this factor, even the gap between walls. There is no simple tool to automatically maintain the distance from before scaling (apart from the _Solidify_ modifier), you simply have to calculate different scaling factors for the outer and the inner part. But that's mathematics, not really a Blender issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. I'm well aware that its not a blender issue. 
My question is about how one would tackle this challenge. 

My guess is, that you would take each vertex and get the distance to the center of the object in an horizontal line - then from there you could somehow add to that. Maybe something with the Normal direction. 
But i cant connect the dots to get it done....

Comment: Well, I didn't look at the tags, in your question itself there was no hint that you are talking about _Geometry Nodes_, sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry i didnt make that more clear. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Gordon says in the commentary, Scaling is a multiplication, and you want an addition.

One way, if you want to use Geometry Nodes, would be to **offset** the vertices by some multiple of their  XY *Position*, normalized to unit length, (thus extracting only their *direction*, in XY, from the object-origin):

[image]

For this result:

[image]

Comment: After doing a quick test in my setup, it seems to do exactly what i was searching for. Thank you very much! 
My former attempts were very much overcomplicated :D 
Again Thanks!